# How to draw circle on canvas that will not be affected by the scaling

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Does anyone know how to make the radius of the circle be fixed although other stuff in the same canvas be scaled. I don't really know how to get the scale factor of the circle dynamically. Thanks

```
    Canvas c = new Canvas(image); 
    c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
    c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null); 
    c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mPaint);
```

`Canvas c = new Canvas(image);`  // This image has a matrix that every time I scaled on the image the cursor will also change. I want the cursor size to stay as 13.0f.

Code:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) { //This is access from the main onDraw();
    paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
   // scaled bitmap base on the scaling of the bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
    if(activateCursor == true){
        if(isTouched == true && ActivityMainEditor.IS_ERASING == true){
            RectF r = new RectF(); 
            matrix.mapRect(r);

            // sol1
            float scaledX = (lastX - r.left) + 48;
            float scaledY = (lastY - r.top) - 137;
            float[] values = new float[9];
            matrix.getValues(values);

            // mScalingFactor shall contain the scale/zoom factor
            float scalex = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
            float skewy = values[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];
            float scale = (float) Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy);
            scaledX /= scale;
            scaledY /= scale;
            // cursor adjustment
```

I have used this lines to make the circle radius will always be the same although scaling the bitmap, but it's not accurate when not scaled yet is okay but when scaled bigger the cursor will got bigger also.

```
            float scaleCursor = (float) Math.sqrt((scalex - 5) * (scalex - 5) + (skewy - 2) * (skewy - 2));
            float cursorSize = (13.0f / scaleCursor); // 13.0f fixed circle radius

            drawACircle(canvas, bitmap, scaledX, scaledY, cursorSize);  
        }
    }

}

private Bitmap drawACircle(Canvas c, Bitmap bm, float cx, float cy, float radius)
{
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas cd = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
    cd.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
    cd.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
 // the line in which the circle will also get scaled :(
    cd.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mPaint);
 // update the main bitmap
    bitmap = bmOverlay;
    if(saveNow == true){
        imageHistory.add(bitmap);
        saveNow = false;
    }
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
c.scale(x,y); // scales the whole canvas (preconcat the matrix with the scale factor)
c.save(); // saves this matrix
// Do all your drawing here except the `drawCircle`.
c.restore(); // restores the original matrix
c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mPaint);
```

Once you call `restore()`, the matrix is returned to the original one. You can now draw the circle in the normal fashion.

**UPDATE**:
Make `x` and `y` as fields in the CustomView, that way you can modify them outside the `onDraw` method. So in the `onTouch` or `onTouchEvent`, you can modify the `x` and `y` and call `invalidate()`. This will call `onDraw` and here it will scale. This will get you what you are looking for. In case of global scaling, always go with the `canvas.scale()` rather than scaling individual draw elements. This will keep things simple.

Comment: What error? What do you mean by `continues scaling and not just one single way` ?

Comment: This method is inside ondraw();  and the bitmap is scaled in onTouched(); so the matrix is always changing. I don't know if the c.save() will save back  the first save canvas matrix. :)

Comment: Hi @Henry, I have updated my question and added code :). I hope it will help.